# How to move a React Native hook call to a hook?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

This is what I simply have in my file:

```
  const isInProgress = progress?.status === 'IN_PROGRESS' ?? false;
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (isInProgress) {
        return setTime(Date.now());
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [isInProgress]);
```

and now I would like to move it to another hook to `utils` file like this:

```
export const useRefreshProgress = (isInProgress: boolean) => {
  const [_, setTime] = useState(Date.now());
  const refreshProgress = useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (isInProgress) {
        return setTime(Date.now());
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [isInProgress]);
  return { refreshProgress };
};
```

and trying to use it like this:

```
  const { refreshProgress } = useRefreshProgress(isInProgress);
  refreshProgress(); // This expression is not callable. Type 'void' has no call signatures.
```

I just started learning React Native.

Comment: I'd also suggest to check the `isInProgress` value *before* calling the `setInterval`. It would be useless to run a timer when there's nothing in progress.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to call refreshProgress. It will be called automatically by useEffect hook when calling useRefreshProgress.

Comment: Of course, you are right,. This are my first steps with that language;) Worked. Thank youl;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Jonas Beck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77810769/5157454), I would also refactor your hook further:

1. Init the state with a function. See [Avoiding recreating the initial state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state).
2. In the `useEffect` bail out early before creating the interval if `isInProgress` is `false`.
3. Return the `time` state, because it might be usable.

Code:

```
const getTime = () => Date.now();

export const useRefreshProgress = (isInProgress: boolean) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(getTime); // lazy init

  const refreshProgress = useEffect(() => {
    if (!isInProgress) return () => {}; // skip if not in progress and return an empty cleanup

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(getTime());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [isInProgress]);

  return time; // return the time because it might be usable
};
```